# I.I.D log returns. What about their square?

Tags: time-series, returns, dependence

If one assumes the underlying return process is I.I.D, is there a solution to the question of the autocorrelation of squared returns?

Thanks.

Comment: Principally I am trying to forecast the volatility of a strategy that is short variance. My simulation of periodic returns does not scale with the square root of time.

Comment: If the returns are truly iid and not simply uncorrelated, then composing them with any function will keep them iid.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question?  You might get more answers that way.

Comment: @rubikscube09: It's a good point you make but I think that the OP meant uncorrelated because otherwise, all of the arch stuff would be useless and engle  probably doesn't get the nobel prize. !!!!! :)